# Capistrano V3 failing on database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I am using the latest version of Capistrano w/ my Rails 4 application. When running `cap dpeloy`. I get a lot of output including this failure:

```
DEBUG [04b6e226] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022135522/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [04b6e226] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022135522/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [04b6e226] Finished in 0.280 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

How do I figure out what is going on here?

**Update #1**

I should say that I have gitignored `config/database.yml` (as was suggested by the capistrano docs). I then added the following to my `config/deploy.rb`

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
```

I then created a file on my VPS at `/var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml`.

Am I not understanding how linked_files works?

**Update #2**

It turns out that the file is actually being linked from `shared/conf/database.yml` to `current/config/database.yml` so now I'm confused as to why it's saying `failed`

**Update #3**

Here is the entire output of my deploy

```
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
 INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
 INFO [37fffef8] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [37fffef8] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/git-ssh.sh )
 INFO [37fffef8] Finished in 0.282 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [d8542e52] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:kyledecot/skateboxes.git on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [d8542e52] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@github.com:kyledecot/skateboxes.git )
DEBUG [d8542e52] Finished in 1.448 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [d8542e52]    e0f96188b9567a84048a0e1238f219abc6351607    HEAD
DEBUG [d8542e52]    e0f96188b9567a84048a0e1238f219abc6351607    refs/heads/master
DEBUG [d8542e52] Finished in 1.448 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [5a13328b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared /var/www/skateboxes/releases on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [5a13328b] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared /var/www/skateboxes/releases )
 INFO [5a13328b] Finished in 0.719 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [293e065b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [293e065b] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config )
 INFO [293e065b] Finished in 0.780 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [4eb81576] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [4eb81576] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [4eb81576] Finished in 0.744 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [89a9e1fa] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/repo/HEAD ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [89a9e1fa] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [89a9e1fa] Finished in 0.734 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO The repository mirror is at /var/www/skateboxes/repo
DEBUG [3cc4d694] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [3cc4d694] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [3cc4d694] Finished in 0.735 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [1cb24a84] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [1cb24a84] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    Fetching origin
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 2)
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    Unpacking objects:  33% (1/3)
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    Unpacking objects:  66% (2/3)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.jects: 100% (3/3)
DEBUG [1cb24a84]    From github.com:kyledecot/skateboxes
DEBUG [1cb24a84]       de7f4a1..e0f9618  master     -> master
 INFO [1cb24a84] Finished in 0.817 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [edd6c793] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [edd6c793] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [edd6c793] Finished in 0.732 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [009b81fe] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [009b81fe] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 )
 INFO [009b81fe] Finished in 0.317 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [e9554374] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [e9554374] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/repo && ( RAILS_ENV=production GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -C /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 )
 INFO [e9554374] Finished in 0.356 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [165a7c40] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [165a7c40] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config )
 INFO [165a7c40] Finished in 1.174 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [c2f7de66] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [c2f7de66] Command: [ -L /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [c2f7de66] Finished in 0.572 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [09de2f2c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml ] on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [09de2f2c] Command: [ -f /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [09de2f2c] Finished in 0.304 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
 INFO [05570e6e] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [05570e6e] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/shared/config/database.yml /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520/config/database.yml )
 INFO [05570e6e] Finished in 0.541 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [8499b753] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/skateboxes/current on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [8499b753] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/skateboxes/current )
 INFO [8499b753] Finished in 0.762 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [bddc6793] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 /var/www/skateboxes/current on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [bddc6793] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022145520 /var/www/skateboxes/current )
 INFO [bddc6793] Finished in 0.289 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [38a6b176] Running /usr/bin/env ls -x /var/www/skateboxes/releases on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [38a6b176] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env ls -x /var/www/skateboxes/releases )
DEBUG [38a6b176] Finished in 0.741 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [38a6b176]    20131022133912  20131022133939  20131022134435  20131022135522  20131022145350
DEBUG [38a6b176]    20131022145520
DEBUG [38a6b176] Finished in 0.741 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO Keeping 5 of 6 deployed releases on 162.243.33.179
 INFO [7da6047f] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022133912 on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [7da6047f] Command: ( RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rm -rf /var/www/skateboxes/releases/20131022133912 )
 INFO [7da6047f] Finished in 0.530 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [7cdd5da9] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [7cdd5da9] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [7cdd5da9] Finished in 0.727 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [906548e8] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch master deployed as release 20131022145520 by kyledecot; " >> /var/www/skateboxes/revisions.log on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [906548e8] Command: echo "Branch master deployed as release 20131022145520 by kyledecot; " >> /var/www/skateboxes/revisions.log
 INFO [906548e8] Finished in 0.279 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: is this file part of your git repository? sure you did not .gitignore it?

Comment: It is indeed ignored. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a failure, see https://github.com/leehambley/sshkit/pull/33.

It says `failed` because that is *not* a file, thus the test command (`[` aka `man (1) test`) has exited with status `1`.

The command in question is coming out of [this code](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/deploy.rake#L66), reproduced below:

```
desc 'Symlink linked files'
task :linked_files do
  next unless any? :linked_files
  on roles :app do
    execute :mkdir, '-pv', linked_file_dirs(release_path)

    fetch(:linked_files).each do |file|
      target = release_path.join(file)
      source = shared_path.join(file)
      unless test "[ -L #{target} ]"
        if test "[ -f #{target} ]"
          execute :rm, target
        end
        execute :ln, '-s', source, target
      end
    end
  end
end
desc 'Check files to be linked exist in shared'
task :linked_files do
  next unless any? :linked_files
  on roles :app do |host|
    linked_files(shared_path).each do |file|
      unless test "[ -f #{file} ]"
        error t(:linked_file_does_not_exist, file: file, host: host)
        exit 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The task name says it all, really, if your file is listed in the `:linked_files` variable, it must exist in `shared_path`, otherwise it will cause Capistrano to abort when the file does not exist.

You haven't yet said whether or not this is causing your deploy to fail, and since you've posted so little of the log, indicating nothing but normal behaviour, nobody can guess.

You appear to be posting logs from the `Symlink linked files` task, which is supposed to *`fail`* on `config/database.yml` if it doesn't exist, it has `failed` to find it, so it does not have to be deleted.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my question w/ more details. Perhaps I'm confused as to what is actually supposed to be happening.

Comment: It's not causing the deploy to fail. I've updated my post w/ the full output.

Comment: I'm just not sure what the problem is here, that's the log of a successful deploy.

Comment: As for why it's saying "failed" see the first link in my answer.

Comment: I guess it's deploying okay but it it's saying "failed" because this file doesn't exist at first (until it symlinks it). The output is somewhat misleading I guess. See a red "failed" just seems like something is going wrong.

Comment: Please see my first link, the link to the pull request where the "the output is misleading" is discussed and fixed pending release.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help. I was really stumped!

Comment: @LeeHambley and there's a way to override that? I'm asking because this code fails on a "cold" deploy where nothing exists... btw thanks for the effors put on cap v3

Comment: You can override any task http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/overriding-capistrano-tasks/, the tasks are defined in plain simple ruby, either in the core Gem, or in the `capistrano-rails` gems, just take a look, and duplicate any code you need to modify into a file loaded by your installation, many choose `./config/deploy/overrides/**/*.rb` for such things.